# Nginx configuration causing too many redirects

Tags: nginx, configuration, directory-structure

I have a conf file with example.com as the root. In the example.com directory, there is an html, css, img, and js folder. I understand this deviates from the traditional html directory as root. I have tried many different configurations (using regex based on filetypes, variables, etc.) but I always get too many redirect errors. Can anyone help on a good conf file for this type of directory structure? Here is my conf file currently.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    # return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    root /var/www/www.example.com/;
    index index.php index.html;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    error_page 404 = error.html?error=404;

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

    location / {
            location ~* \.(html|php)$ {
                   root html/;
            }
            location ~* \.css$ {
                   root css/;
            }
            location ~* \.js$ {
                   root js/;
            }
            location ~* \.(png|jpeg|gif)$ {
                   root img/;
            }
            try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think it should work. What's wrong with it? What is in the logfiles?

Comment: I posted the problem in the answers. It had to do with relative pathing leading to redirect loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the configuration I ended up using:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    # return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    root /var/www/www.example.com/;
    index index.php index.html;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    error_page 404 = /html/error.html?error=404;

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

    location = / {
            try_files /html/index.html =404;
    }

    location / {
            location ~* \.(html|php)$ {
                    try_files $uri /html/$uri =404;
            }
            location ~* \.css$ {
                    try_files $uri /css/$uri =404;
            }
            location ~* \.js$ {
                    try_files $uri /js/$uri =404;
            }
            location ~* \.(png|jpeg|gif)$ {
                    try_files $uri /img/$uri =404;
            }
            try_files $uri =404;
    }
```

}

My problem was that all of my redirects were using relative pathing (such as try_files html/$uri) instead of absolute pathing from the site root (/html/$uri). This lead to redirects like /html/html/html/...

I thought that if I used an absolute path, it would be absolute to the root of the server, and not the site.

My only issue now is that my parameter on my error page redirect (?error=404) doesn't work with absolute pathing, but that not a huge deal.